# How to export seismic attributes in PETREL as excel format?

Tags: excel, petrel

For a given **3D seismic volume** , I have calculated , say , the **instantaneous** **frequency**. Now , I can visualize the **instantaneous** **frequency** for a given section using **Inlines** and **Crosslines**.

But, I want the **instantaneous frequency** data for the whole section in **excel** format?